# Consuming a webservice returning array in C #

Tags: c#, web-services

I have two webservices developed in ADVPL that will be consumed in my application in C # with VS2013 (Windows form).

The first one always returns a string and is working perfectly, but the second and returns an array that I can not consume at all.

It's not a connection problem, because if I change the second webservice to return a string everything works normally, but can not do as array in Visual Studio 2013.

He is returning me the "Can not implicitly convert type" error.

Follows the method of the webservice published and the error generated:

WEBSERVICE REQUEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <_CFILIAL>STRING</_CFILIAL>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

WEBSERVICE RESPONSE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <TARRAY>
      <TESTEARRAY>
         <_CCONTIGENCIA>STRING</_CCONTIGENCIA>
         <_CDIGITAL01>STRING</_CDIGITAL01>
         <_CDIGITAL02>STRING</_CDIGITAL02>
         <_CMATRICULA>STRING</_CMATRICULA>
         <_CNOME>STRING</_CNOME>
         <_CSITUACAO>STRING</_CSITUACAO>
      </TESTEARRAY>
      <TESTEARRAY>
         <_CCONTIGENCIA>STRING</_CCONTIGENCIA>
         <_CDIGITAL01>STRING</_CDIGITAL01>
         <_CDIGITAL02>STRING</_CDIGITAL02>
         <_CMATRICULA>STRING</_CMATRICULA>
         <_CNOME>STRING</_CNOME>
         <_CSITUACAO>STRING</_CSITUACAO>
      </TESTEARRAY>
   </TARRAY>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

CONSUMINDO:

```
WS_FUNCSPONTO.FUNCSPONTO Recebe_Cadastro = new WS_FUNCSPONTO.FUNCSPONTO();
WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY qwert = new WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY();
qwert = Recebe_Cadastro.PEGAINFORM("00");
```

ERRO: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Relogio_Ponto.WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[]' to 'Relogio_Ponto.WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY

Comment: in the client project where you added your service reference go to the web reference folder and right click on the service then select the `configure service reference`. There is a dropdown somewhere saying `Collection Type` make sure it's on `system.array` but in your case seems like a List of List so `System.Collections.Generic.List` might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess since there are multiple  elements it is treated as array. Try this:

```
WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[] qwert = new WS_FUNCSPONTO.TESTEARRAY[10];
qwert = Recebe_Cadastro.PEGAINFORM("00");
```

Instead of getting the response in a single element, receive it in an array.